# How to Convert the svgEdit files into React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Svgedit source code - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit

Major files - svg-editor.html, svg-editor.js

Technologies used - HTML, jQuery, javascript

Is it possible to convert the svgedit source code into the ReactJS components?

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

````
class SVGEdit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let scripts = [
        { src: "redirect-on-no-module-support.js" },
        { src: "redirect-on-lacking-support.js" },
        { src: "jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" },
        { src: "external/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js" },
        { src: "svg-editor.js" }
    ]
    scripts.map(item => { 
        const script = document.createElement("script")
        script.src = item.src
        script.async = true
        document.body.appendChild(script)
    })    
 }
  render() {
     return (
         <div id="svg_container" >
            <div id="svg_editor" role="main">
              .
              .
              .
         </div></div>
     )
  }
}
export default SVGEdit```

Anybody, please share the steps for convert into Reactjs components.
````

Comment: 'it does not work' - Please specify. What did not work? what was expected? What did you see/get instead?

Comment: Actually, I expecting the steps to convert into react components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Actually, the init method is main function of SVG-editor.js, so I have just invoked the method in componentDidMount() like this.

```
import SvgEditor from './svg-editor.js'
   componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
      try {
        // We wait a micro-task to let the svgEditor variable be defined for module checks
        await Promise.resolve()
        SvgEditor.init()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err) // eslint-disable-line no-console
      }
    })()
  }
```